# Power Adapter for travel: Grounding

Tags: europe, power, poland, central-europe

I'm looking for a power adapter than I can use in Poland (coming from India). I can't seem to find anything on how I'm supposed to handle grounded electronics (such as my laptop). Would I need to purchase a European charger (or perhaps just the cable from the power brick to plug)?

Update: I'd like to clarify that this is not a discussion on whether laptops need grounded pins. There are other appliances that use 3-pin leads, like clothing irons.

Comment: Try looking for the phrase "earthed" as well. The cable to brick solution also works well though.

Comment: You don't need a new charger as the voltage adapter is independent of country variations, just make sure you get a three prong wall plug that supports ground

Comment: @CMaster I did try to. Although, most travel adapters I found do support plugging in your grounded device, but don't actually have a ground pin.

Comment: for irons it might be cheaper to buy there instead of bringing your own if you intended to have a long stay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's relatively easy to find country specific grounded adapters (search for Schuko grounded adapter [http://www.amazon.com/Grounded-Universal-Schuko-Adapter-Germany/dp/B004SY5O5K](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004SY5O5K) ) but as far as I am aware there is only one universal (rebranded by Tumi) the Skross [World Adapter PRO+](http://www.skross.com/catalog/show/id/88/name/world-adapter-pro) .

Answer (score 2):

Your laptop is unlikely to require electrical ground. For one, it would make it difficult to operate when on batteries. Various people are disagreeing with me here, very well, the main content of my answer remains unchanged below:

Poland uses type E Euro sockets: http://www.power-plugs-sockets.com/poland/ The ground "pin" is actually part of the socket infrastructure, not on the plug. A high quality adaptor should accommodate the optional ground connection.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good idea to give advice like "unlikely to require an electrical earth". Many laptops do. Only those whose "brick" is marked with the double-insulated square are unlikely, but even those may come with an earthed lead and three-pin plug.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Many countries don't supply ground to ordinary sockets, and in others it is an optional connection you do with a spare wire that comes out the cable to a grounding post on the socket. Yet no one makes specialized adapters per country any more, they just change the plug. If this is some 20 year old bulky brick for some special audio recording purpose that really requires ground [as a reference independent of neutral], then that is a different matter. But for the average traveller buying a commercial laptop, I'm pretty sure the advice is sound.

Comment: @Calchas you will get people who possess certain aluminium bodied notebooks electrocuted . Grab an ohm meter, the body is directly connected to the ground and it is necessary to be so.

Comment: It's not sound at all advice at all. Both my 4yo Dell laptops require an earth because they are not double-insulated, and the OP is asking about his which obviously has a three-pin plug as standard. It's not safe to **assume** that a ground connection is not needed.

Comment: @Calchas how should someone with a Sony Vaio, for example, take your advice?  Here's a picture of the brick, which takes a three-conductor power cable: http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/713tXmY4w5L._SX425_.jpg

Comment: @chx I have an aluminium MacBook presently connected to a two pin US output with no ground in the socket. Even the UK adaptor for it doesn't pass ground to the charger.

Comment: @phoog Here's the US supply for it, with the ground lead not connecting to anything. http://www.laptopbattery-usa.com/images/19.5v-5.13a-adapter.jpg

Comment: OP said it DOESN'T have a ground pin.  That suggests the manufacturer thinks it doesn't need one.  Wait, earlier he said it is grounded.  Need clarification.

Comment: @WGroleau I think ShreyasVinod is suggesting his laptop power cable does have a ground pin on the plug, but none of the converters to type E/F/C he can find will pass ground from the socket to his plug.

Comment: @Calchas My older laptop, has a metallic body and requires grounding, without which you can very much feel the static on the casing. My new laptop is indeed double insulated, but it still _does_ come with a three-pin lead. Almost every pin you will find in India is 3-pin (but they don't necessarily have to be grounded).

Comment: @WGroleau I never said my laptop's power brick isn't 3-pin. I was talking about the travel adapters I've seen so far. I apologise for the confusion.

Comment: @ShreyasVinod It is the same in the UK, but for a switching power supply the ground pin is usually not connected to anything. As I say, you should be able to find a suitable adapter, or purchase a suitable three-pronged "kettle lead" if you wish to use the ground pin. The same charger will be sold in many other countries without the ground pin.

Comment: @Calchas It's a broader question, a laptop was just an example. What about my clothing iron? 3-pin 'travel' iron, only capable of 220-240V at 50/60Hz.

Comment: @ShreyasVinod A metal iron absolutely must be grounded, at least in countries that do provide a protective ground (which includes all of Europe). I have a couple of small scars from burning myself when ironing, fortunately none from electrocuting myself! Again I suggest a high quality adapter that passes ground from the socket to the plug. Note that the ground is not always a pin in the plug, but sometimes it is just supplied at the rim of the socket or in the case of Poland, a pin that sticks out of the socket into the plug.

Comment: Laptop power supplies themselves produce EMI which is typically shunted to ground through the pin. Not having the ground can cause problems with touch screens and such like, as well as potential (ha) safety issues. I

Comment: I doubt you will find a socket with a ground pin (type E) in modern buildings in Poland except for sockets reserved for home appliances. Hotels or conference facilities will most likely provide type C as elsewhere in Europe.

Comment: @Calchas the picture you link to does not show the socket on the adapter, but it will be a 2-pin socket, as in http://thumbs1.ebaystatic.com/d/l225/m/mZM6FWQZY_EPEmDfZxYiGAg.jpg.  The OP's adapter apparently has the three-pin socket.  It's not possible to insert a 2-pin plug into a three-pin socket.  Also, my metal iron (US) is not grounded.

Answer (score 1):

I purchased an earthed adapter in England.  I haven't found it online, but I did find some that look like it.  Some of these state they are not earthed and some don't say:

http://www.go-distribution.co.uk/travel-adapters-and-usb-chargers.html

Comment: It's been impossible to find a good one online. I'll probably have to go look the old fashioned way.